# align thumbnails width with its parent image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I found the code somewhere when googling for learning flex. I am learning it by modifying the code. However I could not fix the alignment for thumbnails and the image above it to match the same width in a responsive way. One image is shifted a bit farther to the right of the image. I tried giving the width for the parent as 75vmin but that did not work.

Here it is

```
<div class="container">
  <section class="product-image col">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li id="slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li id="slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li id="slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li id="slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
      <li id="slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li>
        <a href="#slide1"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw1.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#slide2"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw2.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#slide3"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw3.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#slide4"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw4.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#slide5"><img src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/huijing/filerepo/gh-pages/lw5.jpg" /></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section class="product-detail col">
    <h3>Main title is shown here</h3>
    <p>$45</p>
    <p>mini description is shown here with a toggle button
      which when clicked should show full detail
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.thumbnails {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  line-height: 0;
}

.thumbnails li {
  flex: auto;
}

.thumbnails a {
  display: block;
}

.thumbnails img {
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: top;
  object-position: top;
}

.slides {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
}

.slides li {
  width: 75vmin;
  height: 70vmin;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slides img {
  height: 70vmin;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  -o-object-position: top;
  object-position: top;
}

.slides li:target {
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: slide 1s 1;
}

.slides li:not(:target) {
  -webkit-animation: hidden 1s 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hidden {
  0% {
    z-index: 2;
  }

  100% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}

@keyframes hidden {
  0% {
    z-index: 2;
  }

  100% {
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

The demo is in jsbin as well and here it is

http://jsbin.com/beratikano/1/edit?html,css

should be aligned this way responsively

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: you can see the last thumbnail image is shifted to right. I want the thumbnails to be displayed with respect to the width of the image not far from the big image above it. If there are more thumbnails then it should be shown in another row.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mixing and matching heights and widths.

Your li and the thumbnail container have the same width, which is desired. However, your image is occupying only a part of the li.

If you want the image to resize responsively, it has to have a width of 100% (it will be in relation to its container) and an automatic height. Or the other way around if you're looking for height to be the variable that adapts.

This means that in your code, you also need to let the containing li have an automatic height, so that it will let the image fit without putting it in front of the thumbnails.

Comment: I am not sure I understood you or not but i gave a try by giving width 100% to both thumbnails and li. It is now aligned with respect to the image of slide class width but its not perfect in mobile size

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. The width of your li was fine, it can be whatever you want. The problem was that your image was not filling it up, which means that your image has to have a width of 100% (and a height of auto so that it won't get deformed).

Comment: That said, if you had more thumbnails, you would need to add flex-wrap: wrap to your .thumbnail css.